# On screen artifacts, gone after restart

Tags: gpu, visual-artifacts

I'm experiencing on screen artifacts which lead me to believe that my GPU is dying. However a restart of my pc has (until now) always solved the issue... This again makes it look like it isn't GPU related.

Is there any way to make sure what the cause of the problem is without changing hardware?

Comment: Could you please describe under which conditions do you observe the artifacts and how they look like?

Comment: What is your GPU? Reseting might, among other things, reset the graphics' video memory, that might clear some artifacts. See [this](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html) for reference.

Comment: Same here! Sometimes when I first boot my PC I get a lot of artifacts and after reboot (usually a single one) they are gone. EVGA GTX 770. I'm afraid that my GPU is "dying".